# How define Scope in autofac for Resolved Parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

I need to use context based DI with Autofac. I am using for this OnComponentPreparing method as described here: http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/examples/log4net.html

The reason why I do it this way is, because I need to Inject different configuration depending on the Type it is injected into. Something like this:

- when injecting type A into class implementing interface I1 -> A is created `new A(false)`
- when injecting type A into class implementing interface I2 -> A is created `new A(true)`

I saw some approaches using Named parameters but this is not very good, as you need define separately names for all I1 and I2 implementations. The way as described in the Log4Net example works perfectly.

No I am facing the a problem, that I want to define InstancePerLifetimeScope for instances of *A* class. This seems to be impossible. Do you know some way, how to configure it?

Thx a lot in advance!

Comment: Needing to change based on context like this _may_ indicate an interface design flaw. [We have an FAQ on that.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint! I know those approaches - they are similar as using Named injection. But this is not what I need. Reason: In the FAQ there are some examples using 2 classes only - *PostalServiceSender* and *EmailNotifier* and how to define for each one correct implementation of ISender. Imagine you have 100 classes. You need to define for each one specific configuration. With Ninject you achieve this with 2 lines of code using *WhenInjectedInto<I1>* and *WhenInjectedInto<I2>* for all classes needing ISender interface.